# Javascript: change id of elemnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this elemnt:

```
<table id="listeCalOp"><tbody><tr><td><input name="calOp_date_debut_0" id="calOp_date_debut_0" value="" type="></tr></td></tbody></table>
```

I have change **calOp_date_debut_0** to **calOp_date_debut_22**.

I try this code:

```
var markup = $('<tr>' + $('#listeCalOp').children('tbody:first').find('tr:first').clone().html().replace("calOp_date_debut_0",'calOp_date_debut_22') + '</tr>');
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using jQuery: you can use the `.attr` function like so:

```
$('#my-id').attr('id', 'my-new-id')
```

ref: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need jQuery to change the id of an element. This is vanilla javascript

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("calOp_date_debut_0");
myElement.id = "calOp_date_debut_12"
//if needed
myElement.name = "calOp_date_debut_12"
```

Do you need to clone your element too?

```
var myNewElement = myElement.cloneNode(false)
```

Do you need it with all the inner html (so children) ?

```
var myNewElement = myElement.cloneNode(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make couple of corrections

- You can reach the element to clone via its **id itself**,
- and **no need for cloning** when you are directly using its html.

i.e.

```
var markup = $('<tr>' + $('#calOp_date_debut_0').html().replace("calOp_date_debut_0",'calOp_date_debut_22') + '</tr>');
```

Or you can use `clone` for that element and then append that element to `tr`

```
var $newEl = $('#calOp_date_debut_0').clone();
$newEl.attr( "id", "calOp_date_debut_22" );
var markup = $("<tr></tr>").append( $newEl );
```